# Creating the basic simple Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, oop, data-structures, tree

I'm creating the basic tree which creates nodes and their child. But getting the error when using the print() statement i.e. __ str __( ) to print out the tree layout in the below code.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self,data,children = []):
        self.data = data
        self.children = children
    

    def __str__(self,level=0):
        ret = " " * level + str(self.data) + '\n'
        for child in self.children:
           ret += child.__str__(level+1)
    
        return ret

    # adding the children to the tree node
    def addchildren(self,TreeNode):
        self.children.append(TreeNode.data)

drinks = TreeNode('Drinks',[])
cold = TreeNode('Cold',[])
hot = TreeNode('Hot',[])
cola = TreeNode('Cola',[])
cappucino = TreeNode('Cappucino',[])
drinks.addchildren(cold)
drinks.addchildren(hot)
cold.addchildren(cola)
hot.addchildren(cappucino)

print(drinks)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_944/4195955341.py in <module>
----> 1 print(drinks)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_944/3676504849.py in __str__(self, level)
      8         ret = " " * level + str(self.data) + '\n'
      9         for child in self.children:
---> 10             ret += child.__str__(level+1)
     11 
     12         return ret

TypeError: expected 0 arguments, got 1
```

Why it's throwing this TypeError? And what is the solution?
I'm expecting this:

```
Drinks
 Cold
  Cola
 Hot
  Cappucino
```

And one more thing, please also explain the `def __str__(self,level=0):` method especially `child.__str__(level_1)` cause I have borrowed this print statement.

Comment: You are appending `TreeNode.data`, which isn't a tree node, so it's `__str__` doesn't take the `level=0` argument, **which `__str__` should not be defined to take in the first place**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addchildren` method is broken, it should add `TreeNode` to `self.children`, not `TreeNode.data`:

```
def addchildren(self,TreeNode):
        self.children.append(TreeNode)
```

The `TypeError` is caused by `ret += child.__str__(level+1)`, it is meant to recursively print the child node if each child in `self.children` is also an instance of class `TreeNode`. But it failed and caused the `TypeError` since `TreeNode.data` was added as one of the children.

As the error message `TypeError: expected 0 arguments, got 1` indicated, it tried to invoke `__str__` method for `TreeNode.data`, an instance of the build-in class `str`, which by default does not take any parameter. Because the `__str__` method for user-defined class `TreeNode` is overridden, but the build-in `str` class not.

So it is the same as invoking `'Cold'.__str__(level+1)`, which does not expect any arguments by default.

> object.**str**(self)
> Called by str(object) and the built-in functions format() and print() to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object. The return value must be a string object.
> -- [Python3 Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str__#object.__str__)

Notice that `self` does not count as an argument (at least not in the error message), it is just a convention to have a reference to the object that each class method need to place as the first one in the argument list.

Comment: Got it. Please explain the def __str__() method esp. child.__str__(level+1). And why its throwing this typo error?

Comment: See the modified answer above.